# axios dosen't catch error with axios-auth-refresh library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, axios, try-catch

I am trying to use axios-auth-refresh library installed by npm. I stucked at problem i can't resolve. According to documentation i made code like this:

```
const refreshAuthLogic = (failedRequest) => {
  let tokenData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("REACT_TOKEN_AUTH"));

  if (tokenData) {
    return axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI}/Login/refresh-token`, {
        departmentId: tokenData.departmentId,
        jwtToken: tokenData.jwtToken,
        userId: tokenData.userId,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        localStorage.setItem("REACT_TOKEN_AUTH", JSON.stringify(response.data));

        failedRequest.response.config.headers["Authorization"] =
          "Bearer " + response.data.jwtToken;
        return Promise.resolve();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`refreshed failed`);
        logout();
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
  } else {
    logout();
  }
};

createAuthRefreshInterceptor(axios, refreshAuthLogic, {
  statusCodes: [401],
});
```

Everything works almost perfect but catch never fire up so i can't logout user when refresh token expired. I get answer from api with 401 code but even if i try to put simple console log in .catch() nothing happen.

I have no idea what am i doing wrong? any ideas how to add logout() function to that code that will work?

Comment: That's maybe because of the interceptor.
Axios flow is whenever your request fails first it goes to the interceptor and then comes to your catch. So the response of your refresh-token having 401 code triggers createAuthRefreshInterceptor interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sangam Rajpara, I've found a solution. You need to create a separate instance of axios.

```
const requestToken = axios.create();
```

Then use interceptors for the created instance. You can read about them on the [axios page](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors). Something like this:

```
requestToken.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  (err) => {
    // your log out action
    logout();
    return err;
  }
);
```

Then, in your code instead of axios, use the instance that you created:

```
requestToken
  .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI}/Login/refresh-token`, {
    departmentId: tokenData.departmentId, ...
```

You don't really need that "if" logic anymore